# Change the default Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to change the default application used for creating new rails applications. For me, it is important which gems it uses, which database defaults, which default root path/action, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a application builder,

```
rails new app --builder="/path/to/app/builder"
```

[Descriptions in API Doc](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Rails/AppBuilder.html)

> The application builder allows you to override elements of the
>   application generator without being forced to reverse the operations
>   of the default generator.

In a nutshell, you can define your default set of dependencies before creating a new rails app.

For more info, see this post -> [Rails 3 Application Builders](http://pivotallabs.com/users/mbarinek/blog/articles/1437-rails-3-application-builders)

Answer (score 1):

Just found out there's also a gem available for it:

https://github.com/RailsApps/rails-composer